# Angular - pass action to ng-template via context

Tags: angular, typescript

In Angular i have a template like this:

```html
<ng-template #workflowDialog let-data let-ref="dialogRef" let-cancelAction="cancelAction">
    <button (click)="cancelAction()">Cancel</button>
</ng-template>
```

And i want to pass a cancelAction from `.ts` file like this:

```
this.dialogRef = this.dialogService.open(this.workflowDialog, {
    context: {
        cancelAction: () => {this.router.navigate(["edit"], { relativeTo: this.route });},
    }
});
```

But i get an error `cancelAction_r127 is not a function`...

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: What is `dialogService`? Something you wrote or from angular material?

Comment: Oh sorry... no its Nebular DialogService (https://akveo.github.io/nebular/docs/components/dialog/overview#nbdialogservice)